# What does this mean? $ . test.sh

Tags: shell

I saw the command like "`. test.sh`" in some shell source code,
but I don't know what it does. So, I have tried this.
And, that `.sh` file is executed.

However, I don't understand how "`.`" works.  Can you explain?

Answer (score 4):

The `.` command (which has a synonym, `source`, in `bash`, but not in most other Bourne shell derivatives) reads the named file as part of the current shell.

Consider:

```
$ cat test.sh
export ENVVAR="Welcome"
echo $ENVVAR
$ echo $ENVVAR

$ test.sh
Welcome
$ echo $ENVVAR

$ . test.sh
Welcome
$ echo $ENVVAR
Welcome
$
```

<sup>NB: Cheat 1: I assume `test.sh` is executable. Cheat 2: I assume `test.sh` is in a directory on `$PATH`.</sup>

It means that environment variables set in `test.sh` affect the current shell.  By contrast, executing a command without the `.` does not affect the environment of the current shell.  The `.` mechanism is used when `.profile` and related files are read, for example.

Note that `.` looks for simple names (like `test.sh` with no slash in it) on PATH, but the file only has to be readable; it does not have to be executable.

Comment: Note that when `bash` is not in POSIX mode, `.`/`source` also checks the current directory if no file is found using `PATH`.

Comment: @chepner: That's entirely plausible. I haven't bothered to experiment with whether the current directory is searched first or last.  For the most part, it is not important to this question, which is about the high-level difference between sourcing and executing a script.  I agree, though, that it does matter if you're going to make a bullet-proof system depending on such a script.

Answer (score 3):

It's a shorthand for this, nothing more:

```
source test.sh
```

http://ss64.com/bash/period.html

Comment: The `dot` command pre-dates the `source` command by years.  It was in the original Bourne shell.  The C shell had the `source` command for the same job; `bash` imported that as a synonym for `.` some time later.